# Make iterations of a loop sequentially in Mutiny

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

I am new in the reactive programming world. I am currently working in a Java reactive application using the Mutiny library.

I need to develop a loop that waits for the previous iteration to finish in order to start the next one. For instance:

```
List<Uni<T>> uniList = new ArrayList<>();
for (T item : items) { //items is an already fulfilled collection
    uniList.add(this.doSomethingAndReturnInUni(item));
}


return Uni.combine().all().unis(uniList).combinedWith(unisToCombine -> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    unisToCombine.forEach(x ->list.add(x));
    return list;
  });
```

The **for loop** in the example, generates a thread per iteration. I am wondering how to order the i-th call to the method *doSomethingAndReturnInUni()* waits for the (i-1) call to trigger the event, that is, make the for loop sequentially. It is possible to suscribe those events in such a way?

Comment: I have achieve something like this in Vertx using Future. I have used Recursion for that, I convert my list of items to iterator. I pass that iterator to function and everytime it does iterator.next(). on completion of Future I check if iterator has items I will function again.

Comment: The are words misspelled where I don't trust the closest word to be intended - in the title `secuentially`, in the body `iteation`. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using uni, as this should just handle one operation, for loops you should use multi, where you can handle the back pressure, and only get the next event, when one event is finished. Multi can be run sequentially and in parallel.

see https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-back-pressure/